# Numerical stability of tf.reduce_mean

Tags: python, tensorflow, precision

Numerical stability of `tf.reduce_mean` is worse than `np.mean`, on both cpu and gpu.

Does `tf.reduce_mean` have numerical problem whenever the sum exceeds the limit of the floating point type?

Is there a better way to calculate mean for a `float16` array in tensorflow?

Result (cpu, tf 1.13.1, linux):

```
np.mean 64: 0.499978537075602
np.sum  64: 499978.53707560204
np.mean 16: 0.5
np.sum  16: inf
tf.reduce_mean 16: nan
```

Result (gpu, compute capability 5.2, tf 1.13.1, cuda 10.1, linux):

```
np.mean 64: 0.500100701606694
np.sum  64: 500100.7016066939
np.mean 16: 0.5
np.sum  16: inf
tf.reduce_mean 16: nan
```

Result (gpu, compute capability 7.0, tf 1.13.1, cuda 9.0, linux):

```
np.mean 64: 0.4996047117607758
np.sum  64: 499604.7117607758
np.mean 16: 0.4995
np.sum  16: inf
tf.reduce_mean 16: nan
```

Test:

```
"""
Test numerical stability of reduce_mean
"""

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


N = int(1e6)
dtype = np.float16

x = np.random.random(size=N)

print("np.mean 64:", np.mean(x))
print("np.sum  64:", np.sum(x))
x = x.astype(np.float16)
mean16 = np.mean(x)
print("np.mean 16:", np.mean(x))
print("np.sum  16:", np.sum(x))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.constant(x, dtype=np.float16)
    print("tf.reduce_mean 16:",
          sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(x)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result:

```
tf.reduce_mean, tree reduction: 0.5
```

Test:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


N = int(1e8)
x = np.random.random(size=N).astype(np.float16)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.reshape(x, (100, 100, 100, 100))
    for i in range(4):
        a = tf.reduce_mean(a, axis=-1)
    print("tf.reduce_mean, tree reduction:", sess.run(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

From [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html):

> By default, float16 results are computed using float32 intermediates for extra precision.

From [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_mean):

> Please note that np.mean has a `dtype` parameter that could be used to specify the output type. By default this is `dtype=float64`. On the other hand, `tf.reduce_mean` has an aggressive type inference from `input_tensor`...

So probably no better way than `sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(x, np.float32))))`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and get an outcome of `0.5`. I'm using Tensorflow 1.13.1 with GPU.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.random.random(size=10**8).astype(np.float16)
px = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float16, shape=(None,), name="x")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf.reduce_mean(px), feed_dict={px: x}))
```

Comment: I'm using linux and tensorflow 1.13.1 from anaconda. What is the compute capability of your gpu?

Comment: Me too. I'm on Windows 10 though.

Comment: My GPU's compute capability is 5.0.

Comment: got same result when I run your code on the 5.0 gpu. I heard `feed_dict` is slower than a Tensor (and also tf.queue). So I can't use that all the time.

Comment: Actually I can't run the code you provided. The `tf.constant` call stuck (when it tries to put the huge array into the graph). When I reduce the array size to 10**5 the `tf.constant` call terminates and `tf.reduce_mean` gets a result of 0.0.

Comment: I changed array size N to 1e6 and re-ran the test on all 3 machines.

Comment: I got the same result. As explained in the doc linked from the other answer, the behavior of `tf.reduce_mean` call on constants seems to be in line with `np.mean(x, dtype=np.float16)`.